# VB.NET: Manufacturer name of a network device from ip address

Tags: vb.net, networking

Using VB.NET, How can I get the manufacturer name of a device connected to my router if I know the device ip address and mac address?
Just like Advanced IP Scanner do it in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You can use the first 3 octets of the MAC address to lookup the manufacturer.  It may be that the tool you reference has a database of these or looks them up on the web

Comment: @MartinParkin, the OUI of a MAC address can tell you the manufacturer of the network interface, which may not be the same as the manufacturer of the device itself. See [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/26597/8499) about that problem.

Comment: @MartinParkin thank you. please post it as an answer, to mark it as the right answer.

Comment: @MegamindSaiko I've added this now, as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comment I added to the question above:

> You can use the first 3 octets of the MAC address to lookup the manufacturer.
>
> It may be that the tool you reference has a database of these or looks them up on the web.

As mentioned by Ron Maupin, the OUI of the MAC address will tell you the manufacturer of the network interface, which may not necessarily be the manufacturer of the device itself.  See this link (as provided by Ron): [Manufacturer and wireless cards OUI](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/26597/8499)